# How to pass dynamic value to another plugins options in Jquery (from accordion to localscroll)

Tags: jquery, scroll, accordion

So here's my setup.
On my page I have two columns. Inside the left column I have a accordion and below that i have some text with links inside it. In the right column I have some pictures that are being controlled by the links inside the text in the left column.The images can be scrolled.

On my page I have a accordion that works fine and is setup like this

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    autoHeight: false,
    navigation: true,
    change: function(event, ui) { dynamicOffsetValue(); }/*This here call's the dynamicOffsetValue function after the accordion has finished animation*/
});
```

Then I have a function that gives me the height of a div that is wrapped around the accoridon

```
function dynamicOffsetValue()
{
    var top = $("#accordion").height();/*IF I ALERT THIS THEN IT GIVES ME THE NUMBER I NEED*/
}

dynamicOffsetValue();
```

Then I also have a localscroll plugin setup for the images in the right column

```
  var scrollOptions = {
      target:div#overflow, /* the element that has the overflow and contains images*/
      offset:500,/*HOW TO I MAKE THIS EQUAL TO dynamicOffsetValue ???*/
      axis: 'xy',
      duration: 50,  
      easing: 'swing'
    };

$('.scrollContainer').localScroll(scrollOptions);/*.scrollContainer(this element wraps both left and right column) */
```

Right now when the page loads and the first accordion is open and user clicks on a link that's inside the text , then the images get scrolled right where I want. But when the Accordion is opened in a different state then offset value 500 is not enough.

How would I go about making it so that when the user clicks on on the accordion, then the dynamicOffsetvalue get's sent to scrollOptions and then when the user clicks on a link inside the text(this fires the localscroll) the new offset value is read?

Hope all of this makes some sense. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use anchors in links (`href="#my_id"`) and add those id to images you want, instead of setting offset?

Answer (score 0):

Well as usual, a little bit time after posting this question, the answer just came to me.(I had been messing around with it for two days )

This is my final setup.
I guess my problem was that the links inside the text got localscroll assigned to them only on page load, thus disregarding any updates to scrollOptions . But now that I have moved all of the localscroll setup inside my dynamicOffset function, it(localscroll) gets re assigned every time a accordion section is clicked and then it(localscroll) reads the new updated offset value.

```
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        autoHeight: false,
        navigation: true,
        change: function(event, ui) { dynamicOffsetValue(); }/*This here call's the dynamicOffsetValue function after the accordion has finished animation*/
    });


    function dynamicOffsetValue()
    {
        var top = $("#accordion").height();/*IF I ALERT THIS THEN IT GIVES ME THE NUMBER I NEED*/

          var scrollOptions = {
          target:'div#overflow', /* the element that has the overflow and contains images*/
          offset:top,/*THIS NOW EQUALS TOP*/
          axis: 'xy',
          duration: 50,  
          easing: 'swing'
        };

    $('.scrollContainer').localScroll(scrollOptions);/*.scrollContainer(this element wraps both left and right column) */

    }

    dynamicOffsetValue();
```